# Why getComputedStyle contain visibility as visible?

Tags: javascript, css, getcomputedstyle

Why getComputedStyle returns element visibility as `visible` even if you never set visibility to be hidden or visible.

Example:
`getComputedStyle($('#block1')[0],null).visibility;` --- "visible"

and at the same time:
`$('#block1')[0].style.visibility` ---  ""

Comment: Because elements are visible by default?

Comment: so when you will hide parent, it became to be hidden, but real element property is ""

And yes it is visible by default. But i don't think it's related.

Comment: That's two different things. The `visibility` style rule is the empty string (inherit from parent), but `getComputedStyle()` actually computes the actual style value (in this case, `visible`).

Comment: Hmmm, yes you are right, we need to get height and width counted automatically from any place too, i just thought that if property isn't set it should be "" in computed style as well. I was wrong.

Comment: Frédéric, put your answer as a real answer so Rantiev can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

The default for most existing DOM elements that require rendering to the `document` is `visibility: visible`. These properties only apply themselves once the element is rendered and are computed without being applied to the `style` object of a DOM element. The `getComputedStyle` method is there to pick up these rendered properties which are either from the browser's default configuration or from the stylesheet.

Comment: Unrelated to this post; I think the information you provided [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/229477) is valuable but IMHO it should be posted as another answer.

Comment: Thanks... I would do this but this guy covers it: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/302656/190171
And the answer given is out of date and might be misread so I felt it was worth highlighting in the post itself? If that's not the way of stackoverflow then skip the edit

Comment: Ah, right. That's indeed some kind of flaw in the Stack Exchange system. It would help if the OP accepted the other answer. Or if we had a system where old votes 'fade away' - they would count towards reputation but not towards sorting answers by votes.

Comment: I added a comment instead